# Sonarqube scan for JPA performance

Tags: performance, jpa, sonarqube

I would like to know if Sonarqube could discover bad smells in JPA usage, for example the famous [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) problem. If there is no such scanner, how does your team manage them during development? Thanks.

Comment: There are no rules regarding this in the java plugin today. I would, as java analyzer dev, would be interested what kind of piece of code would allow you to detect such issue in your opinion. Feel free to send detailed suggestion to sonarqube@googlegroups.com